# Cursor in SQL Server only getting every other record

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a SQL Server Agent job (executes a stored procedure) that runs each day that adds any new databases to our maintenance jobs. I would like to create a new stored procedure that will remove any job steps from the maintenance jobs for those databases that have been deleted.

Below is what I currently have, but when it's executed it will only remove every other record. I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
DECLARE @dblist TABLE (id int identity (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                       dbname nvarchar(128),
                       job_id uniqueidentifier,
                       step_id int);
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128);
DECLARE @stepid int;
DECLARE @jobid uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @jobname2 sysname;

INSERT INTO @dblist (dbname, job_id, step_id)
SELECT database_name as dbname,
       js.job_id,
       js.step_id
from msdb..sysjobsteps as js
     INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobs as j ON js.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE database_name NOT IN ('master', 'msdb', 'model','tempdb', 'MET', 'default_db')
  AND database_name NOT IN (SELECT sdb.name
                            FROM sys.sysdatabases as sdb
                                 INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobs AS j ON js.job_id = j.job_id
                            WHERE sdb.name = js.database_name );

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT job_id,
           step_id
    FROM @dblist;

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @jobid, @stepid;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb..sp_delete_jobstep @job_id = @jobid, @step_id = @stepid;


    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @jobid, @stepid;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BREAK;

END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Comment: I can't see that that would skip rows from the table `@dblist`, which either makes me think that the rows in that table aren't what you think they are, or there's something *else* in your SQL we don't know about.

Comment: That is all of my SQL. I will investigate further to make sure my table is what I expect. Usually before I execute the script I run the SELECT statement, then run it again after execution. That is where I am seeing every other record has been removed from job steps.

Comment: `select * from @dblist` before you run your cursor, then within the cursor `select @jobid, @stepid`. Run first with `exec` commented out then again without commenting out. See if it misses any rows.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out or removing the redundant `IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK;` at the end of the while loop?

Comment: Maybe I am crazy but is only one fetch next just enough?

Comment: It turns out that the problem was not the cursor, but that the job_id and step_id of each job changes when one is deleted. To fix the issue I needed the query to run in the loop so the new ids would be updated. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you don't have an ORDER BY clause in the query that defines the cursor.

However, if you have a table variable like that and it has an ID column as an identity, don't go using a cursor in the first place. That's a whole lot of resources that aren't needed.

Just use a simple counter and select the data row by row.